# What are some strategies to apply when trying to integrate the reciprocal of the product of $(1+x^2)((1-X^2)^{1/2})$?

Tags: calculus, roots

I tried to solve a problem my friend gave me but I find it extremely tough.

How do I find the integral of $$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2)^{\frac12}}?$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @ADITYA I tried to simplify it somehow but I just can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Solution]

Hope the image is crystal clear..

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm wondering when I should make trigonometric substitution.

Comment: the answer is that it comes with practice...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the link..

Answer (score 0):

set $$t=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ then we get $$x=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}$$ and $$dx=\pm\frac{1}{2}(1-t^2)^{-1/2}(-2t)dt$$
again
Setting
$$x=\sin(t)$$ and we get $$dx=\cos(t)dt$$
and our integral will be
$$\int\frac{\cos(t)}{(1+\sin(t)^2)\sqrt{1-\sin(t)^2}}dt$$
i think this works

Comment: I tried substitution but this complicates the problem further.

Comment: Now I have $(2-(t^2))((1-(t^2))^{1/2})$ in the denominator. Thank you for replying in any case.

Comment: ok, try $$x=\cosh(t)$$ i will back in a few minutes

Comment: a possible solution should be $$-1/2\,\sqrt {2}\arctan \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1}x}{{x
}^{2}-1}} \right) 
$$

Comment: Directly we can set x to cos(t)

Comment: I think we can avoid hyperbolic functions. I have little experience with those.

Comment: Your answer will work as well @Dr.SonnhardGraubner , I think. Mr. ADITYA used cos theta.

Comment: No mister please i am a student ...